# Scala : Calling methods of a class during object initialization

Tags: scala, object-initialization

```
object Program {
   def main(args:Array[String])={
      val parent = new Parent{
         method()
      }
   }
}


class Parent{
   def method(){
       println("inside method")
   }
}
```

In the above code, I am instantiating a new instance of Parent class. Now I thought this is similar to C# object initialization syntax. But I am able to call some methods here as well. What is this use case of this feature? Does this have any name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you are instantiating an instance of an anonymous class that extends `Parent`, and calling a base class method from within the constructor. I don't think there is any special name for it.

Comment: That didnt occur to me. Thanks